# jQuery price calculator with multiple select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to add/remove a price form a span (quote-price) when a button and select menus are selected. The following code works great for the buttons and for when I am using just one select menu, however when I use multiple select menus, it fails. Does anyone know how I can adjust the below code to work with multiple select menus?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function updateTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        $('button.selected').each(function() {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        total += parseFloat($('select').val());
        $('span.quote-price').text("£" + total.toFixed(2));
    }

    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        updateTotal();
    });
    $('select').change(updateTotal);

    $('.reset').click(function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('select').val('0.00');
        updateTotal();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the HTML you are using also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just immitate the code you already have for the button. Instead of this:

```
total += parseFloat($('select').val());
```

..use this:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

That will add the value for every select on the page to the variable `total`. In case you just want some selects (you might have them for other reasons on your page), add a class (like `price` for instance) to them, and change the selector to `select.price`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function updateTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        $('button.selected').each(function() {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $('select').each(function() {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $('span.quote-price').text("£" + total.toFixed(2));
    }

    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        updateTotal();
    });
    $('select').change(updateTotal);

    $('.reset').click(function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('select').val('0.00');
        updateTotal();
    });
});
```

Instead of

`total += parseFloat($('select').val());`

I used

```
$('select').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: That broke it all unfortunately

Comment: Could you elaborate on "broke"? What happends? Any errors in the console? The answer looks right to me.

Comment: user must have missed something while copy pasting above code